# How to create a form dropdown - angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular

I have a form written in html on a page and there is a button above the form. 
    Now i want to know the functionality i can add to the button so that when i press the button, it will directly add the same form i have on the page already just beneath it so i can make multiple submissions.

//form

```
<button>Add Form</button>
<form>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="title">Title</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="title" name="title" placeholder="Title">
      </div>
   </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about the problem.

Comment: When i click on the add form button, it should drop down the same form which i already have on the page, just beneath the initial form so i can make multiple submission

Answer (score 1):

```
<button (click)=" Add some value to forms array  ">Add Form</button>
<div *ngFor="let form of forms">
    <form>
        <!-- Your Form -->
    </form>
</div>
```

Comment: above is not code ... just path to your problem ... you should implement it with code

Comment: so i have to create a loop for the form basically?

Comment: an explanation with the code usually helps the question asker understand better